# How To Make Button Add EditText Input to a Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a Save button:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:onClick="saveEvent"/>
```

And when it is pressed, I want it to add the EditText input to a Listview. The the Listview and EditText+Save Button elements are on different XML layouts, by the way.

I have an activity called SaveEvent, that happens when the Save button is pressed. How do I make it add the EditText input to the ListView element?

Thank you so much.

A piece of MakeEvent.java:

```
    public void saveEvent(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SaveEvent.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

SaveEvent.java:

```
    package com.kass.planner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SaveEvent extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btn;
    private EditText et;
    private ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);

        // set the lv variable to your list in the xml
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.event_list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String input = et.getText().toString();
        if (input.length() > 0) {
            // add string to the adapter, not the listview
            adapter.add(input);
            // no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as it is done by the adapter.add() method
        }
    }
```

But this code doesn't work... ^ Thank you.

Comment: This code should work assuming you want to show that listview within the SaveEvent activity

Comment: I think you should clarify "the Listview and EditText+Save Button elements are on different XML layouts" because how are you able to reference those different views on those layouts within a single Activity?

Comment: In response to your other comment. Start simple. So one XML and one activity. The root element is a vertical LinearLayout. It has 2 elements. A RelativeLayout and a ListView. Inside the RelativeLayout put the EditText and the button. Then start hooking up the Java code

Answer (score -2):

upon enlightenment from cricket guy and revisiting some of my old programs
instead of updating the adapter object

only update the underlining data
and call the following method to Bind the list view object with the updated adapter object

```
public void fillList() {

    ArrayAdapter<String>   adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getItems());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

   }
```

I Agree. not memory efficient but it works well

Comment: i doubt it, but with all shiny medals u have due enlighten me. what do u have in mind? and down voting wasn't that merry :-(

Comment: I was simply asking why you thought this was the solution, maybe updating the answer with more details would be useful to others with the problem. To enlighten you, first, it's recommended to try to either run the code or understand the implementation of the API. For example, reseting the adapter isn't necessary because the adapter itself has not changed, only the underlying data. Second, if you try to run this code with the poorly explained description of the problem, I feel like the list should be updating as expected

Comment: care to comment if u have time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to show. You create a brand new adapter and reload the list with the new data? I'm telling you, try making a simple activity with an ArrayAdapter, call `adapter.add` with some data, and the ListView updates. You don't need to add to the Arraylist, but if you do, you must call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged`. You only reset the adapter if you have a brand new ArrayList reference

Comment: that notifyDataSetChanged method wasn't displaying the updated data,.. thanx though i will give it a try.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you guys. Does that mean that the ListView and EditText + Save button can be different XML layouts, but they have to be on the same activity? I was just looking for a code snippet, of how to add EditText input as a ListView item, thank you.